# how to make a IOS app with parse by AWS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, parsing

all.

I want to make a IOS app with parse by AWS.
I watched [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sd2bphvVzGy][1]

this is Appdelegate.swift file.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let parseConfig = ParseClientConfiguration{ (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) in

            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "myappid"
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "mymasterkey"
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "http://ec2-13-124-93-153.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com/parse"
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        }

        Parse.initialize(with: parseConfig)
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

I want to know how to get the information that "applicationId" and " Clientkey" from AWS. I cannot get the way to get the information at internet. anyone help me?

and if i run it.
there are wrong response.

```
2017-04-19 22:37:00.668 wanote[3667:493599] [Error]: unauthorized (Code: 0, Version: 1.12.0)
Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=0 "unauthorized" UserInfo={error=unauthorized, NSLocalizedDescription=unauthorized, temporary=0})
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 15
```

could you teach me what is problem?

Best regards.

Comment: You need to run your parse server at `http://ec2-13-124-93-153.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com/parse`. I don't see that your server is running, it is giving `{"error":"unauthorized"}`. First try to run the server and check whether endpoint is working correctly or not.

Comment: This might help https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/how-to-set-up-parse-server-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/